# Taylor series with point of expansion.

Tags: calculus

Write the Taylor series for the function $f(x)= x^2-3x+1$ using $x=2$ as the point of expansion , i.e. write a formula for $f(2+h)$

Even though I know what Taylor Expansion is I am really confused what the point of expansion is and how to find $f(2+h)$

Comment: Rewrite $x^2-3x+1$ as a quadratic in $x-2$; $$f(x)=x^2-3x+1=(x-2)^2+(x-2)-1$$This is the Taylor series about $x=2$. Now for $x=2+h$ we have $x-2=h$ hence $$f(2+h)=h^2+h-1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably accustomed to Taylor series about $x=0$.  In general, the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) about $x=a$ is $$f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\cdots.$$

So, we compute the derivatives $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, and so on (since this is a polynomial, it'll have a finite number of non-zero derivatives).  We use them to find the values $f'(a)$, $f''(a)$, and so on, then substitute them into the above equation.  In this case $a=2$.