# How does Wolfram Alpha perform Taylor Expansions of functions about singular points?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series, wolfram-alpha, singularity

I am trying to use a Taylor Expansion to expand a function about a singular point `z_0` to obtain a Laurent Series about the point `z_0`. As an example, consider the function

`f(z) = exp(2z) / (1-z)^3 about z_0=1`

First, I converted the denominator from `(1-z)^3` to `-(z-1)^3`. I've done Taylor Expansions about non-singular points many times [using this process](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/487814/402217). According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783775/laurent-series-about-singular-point-for-left-frac1x1-ax-right-frac#comment3640977_1783775), it is impossible to do a Taylor Expansion about a singular point. Yet, [typing the operation into Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expand+-exp(2z)%2F(z-1)%5E3+about+z%3D1) produces the correct Laurent Series.

How can I manually reproduce the output returned by Wolfram Alpha? I'd appreciate even the smallest hint, as my problem is that evaluating the function and a few consequent derivatives at `z=z_0` returns `.../0`, as is [easier to see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY0HZ.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This could be a too simplistic answer.*

Let $z=1-x$ which makes $$f=\frac{e^{2-2 x}}{x^3}=e^2\,\frac{e^{-2 x}}{x^3}$$ Expand the exponential as a Taylor series $$e^{-2 x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2x)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 2^n x^n}{n!}$$ which make $$f=e^2\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 2^n x^{n-3}}{n!}=e^2\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 2^n(1-z)^{n-3}}{n!}=e^2\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2n-1} 2^n(z-1)^{n-3}}{n!}$$ and then the result.

Comment: There is one part I do not follow. Why did the summation go from `...x^n` (middle line) to `...x^(n-3)` (bottom line)? EDIT: I think it's related to the power of the singular term in the denominator, but I don't see why it's ok to do that since the expanded term is the numerator.

Comment: @mikey. We have to divide the expansion of $e^{-2x}$ by $x^3$ to get $f$.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @mikey. You are very welcome !

Comment: I'm working through the problem. There is one more part I don't follow, after which I can obtain the result. From the second-to-last step to the last step, the numerator changes from `(-1)^n` to `(-1)^(2n-1)`. I do understand that `(1-z)^(n-3) = -(z-1)^(n-3)`. Just in case it's easier to see on paper, [here's what I mean](https://i.imgur.com/tUOMEgv.jpg). Why doesn't the minus sign carry through and alternate with each term?

Comment: @mikey. $(1-z)^{n-3}=(-1)^{n-3} (z-1)^{n-3}=(-1)^{n-1} (z-1)^{n-3}$

Comment: Right. `(-1)^(n-3) ≠ (-1)^n`. (I should've caught that). Thanks again.